# IntelliJ: “Output exceeds cutoff limit” in scala worksheet

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

How can I grow the number of output lines in IntelliJ, such that I do not receive any more this message in Scala worksheet:

```
Output exceeds cutoff limit.
```

[image: screenshot of worksheet]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

File -> Settings... -> Languages and Frameworks -> Scala -> "Worksheet" tab -> "Output cutoff limit, lines" option

[image: screenshot of option]

Comment: This is odd, but changing this option does absolutely nothing for me.